# Android app crashes on image selection button click

Tags: java, android, oop, memory, crash

App crashes once Gallery/Camera buttons is clicked:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWriteToParcel(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel(Bitmap.java:2157)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:2538)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2439)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSparseArray(Parcel.java:1422)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2463)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:2157)
    at android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityClientController.java:1257)
    at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:99)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
```

My app basically gets user inputs(string/int values and multiple image Uri) and construct a Record instance, where this instance is 8 arguments, each argument is a different class type that has multiple attributes along with a unique image Uri array.
User input is divided to 3 phases, each phase happens in a different Fragment

1. fragment1 takes 3 arguments (user inputs) Record(A,B,C)
2. fragment2 takes 2 arguments Record(A,B,C,D) using setters of course, so far no crashes the log of record.tostring is populated as intended.
3. fragment3 app crashes when any gallery/button is clicked
   [Fragment3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsBjr.jpg)

- Memory usage is max 250mb which is fine?
- App doesn't crash on android emulator but tested multiple modern android devices and they all crashed

```
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent data = result.getData();
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if (imageBitmap != null) {
                    Uri capturedImageUri = getImageUri(requireContext(), imageBitmap);
                    handleGalleryOrCameraResult(capturedImageUri, requestCode);
                } else {
                    // Handle when the imageBitmap is null
                }
            }
        }
    }

        private void handleGalleryOrCameraResult(Uri selectedImageUri,int requestCode) {
        // Use the appropriate list based on the current scenario
        List<Uri> imageList;
        TextView imageCounter;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        // Determine the scenario based on your logic
        // For example, you can use a flag to identify whether it's for container, lock, or item

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 7: // Container
                imageList = DamageGoodImageUris;
                imageCounter = DamageGoodImageCounter;
                recyclerView = DamageGoodRecyclerView;
                break;
            case 8: // Lock
                imageList = HeatImageUris;
                imageCounter = HeatImageCounter;
                recyclerView = HeatRecyclerView;
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }

        // Add the selected image URI to the respective model's image list
        if (selectedImageUri != null) {
            imageList.add(selectedImageUri);
        }

        // Update the RecyclerView with the new image list
        setupRecyclerView(recyclerView, imageList, imageCounter);
    }
        // Helper method to get Uri from Bitmap
    private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Viewmodel didn't work

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing the complete stack trace of the crash and the code that generates that stack trace.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);` You can remove those lines as result not used.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write a Bitmap to a Parcel or Bundle.  There's a size limit on that-  about 2 MB.  A Bitmap is generally way too large.  Instead of writing the bitmap itself, write the file or URI of the bitmap, and reopen it when you read from the parcel.

Comment: I have tried that approach didn't work,
I also tried to make this fragment as my first fragment after the main activity ( I didnt pass any bitmap to it) 
and still crashes

Comment: wow i can't believe how silly the fault was!
I finally was able to figure out the issue!
it was a signaturePad, i removed it from my layout and worked just like charm!
turned out to be how the bitmap from the signature pad is being handled was causing the crash.
any suggestions on a how to use a signaturepad ? other than this one
               ``` <com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad ```

Comment: With no offense meant-  using random github libraries nobody has ever heard of without an update in the last 3 years is usually a very bad idea.  Even if there's nothing malicious in there, that doesn't scream high quality code.  Unless something is a well known and actively supported library I wouldn't touch it.  And even then I'd be actively auditing their source code before using it.

Comment: no offense taken at all, still a lot for me to learn in this journey, how would you apply a signaturepad if you were me?